Difference Between Bayah of Khilafah & Choosing Leader For Imarah
As per scholars giving Bayah to anyone other than Khalifah is bid'ah.
In Islam only two forms of governance are held true form one Khilafah and other is Imarah based on the hadith below as per Fuqaha:
But how can leader be chosen for Imarah when Bayah is required but it reserved only for Khalifah

عن أبي سعيد وأبي هريرة رضي الله عنهما مرفوعاً: إذا خرج ثلاثة في سفر
فَلْيُؤَمِّرُوا أحدهم.

[Abu Dawood]

Please note that the 'usool-ul-fiqh' tag should be used for questions on the general science of jurisprudence, not on questions on specific rulings. An example of a question that fits this tag is: Why aren't all commands of the Prophet treated as obligatory?
